# $compile not work in recursive functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My JavaScipt code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.number=10;
    $scope.init = function(i) {
        var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#play'));
        var el = '<h1>{{number}}</h1>';
        el += '<h1>'+i+'</h1>';
        var generated = element.html(el);
        $compile(generated.contents())($scope);
        if(i==0) {
            return false;
        }
        setTimeout($scope.init, 1000, i-1);
    }
});
```

First time when the function init is called {{number}} It is shown as 10, but when the function init() is called again $cope.number appear as  {{number}}. My question is: why $compile doesn't work well?

Comment: First thing to check is to replace `setTimeout` with angular `$timeout` service. Calling `$scope.$digest()` may also help.

Comment: @csharpfolk: It's `$timeout`.

Comment: This is so not the angular way.  Angular isn't about manipulating the DOM in this manner, you are trying to use angular like it's a DOM manipulation framework instead of the Data Binding framework it was written to be.

Comment: @Claies I am glad to hear that you know many frameworks and a lot of theory, but I would have preferred to answer the question.

Comment: I'm glad that the answer you received worked for your situation, but I really fail to see the value that is gained by using a recursive function for this rather than using the `$interval` service in angular.  If you are interested in the angular way of doing this, I can write an answer showing `$interval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://plnkr.co/edit/ot2CNgUzZoZgIBsgMuCF?p=preview

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("mtCtrl", function($scope, $compile, $timeout) {
    $scope.number=10;
    $scope.init = function(i) {
        var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#play'));
        var el = '<h1>{{number}}</h1>';
        el += '<h1>'+i+'</h1>';
        var generated = element.html(el);
        $compile(generated.contents())($scope);
        if (i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $timeout(function () {
          $scope.init(i-1);
        }, 1000);
    };
    $scope.init(10);
});
```